# Google Sheets auto increment column B with empty cells restarting from 1 at each new category String in Column A instead of continuous incrementing

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, count, google-sheets-formula, countif

I found this partial solution to my problem:

[Google Sheets auto increment column A if column B is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73193498/10789707)

With this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B&ROW($B$2:$B),FILTER($B$2:$B&ROW($B$2:$B),$B$2:$B<>""),0)))`

What I need is the same but instead of continuous numbers I'd need it to restart incrementing from 1 at each new category string on an adjacent column (column A in example below, categories strings are A, B, C, D etc.).

For example:

[image: COLUMNS C AND D]

Problem with formula in C12 and C15 (added numbers 1 and 2)

Needed result in column D, as with D11 and D19 restarts incrementing from 1 at new category string)

| 1 |  |  |  | needed result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | A |  |  |  |
| 4 | A |  |  |  |
| 5 | A | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | A |  |  |  |
| 7 | A |  |  |  |
| 8 | A |  |  |  |
| 9 | A | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | A |  |  |  |
| 11 | B | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | B |  | 1 |  |
| 13 | B |  |  |  |
| 14 | C | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 15 | C |  | 2 |  |
| 16 | C |  |  |  |
| 17 | C | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 18 | C |  |  |  |
| 19 | D | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 20 | D |  |  |  |
| 21 | D |  |  |  |
| 22 | D | 1 | 8 | 2 |
| 23 | D |  |  |  |
| 24 | D | 1 | 9 | 3 |
| 25 | D |  |  |  |
| 26 | D |  |  |  |
| 27 | D | 1 | 10 | 4 |
| 28 | D |  |  |  |
| 29 | D |  |  |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A&B2:B, A2:A&B2:B, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A&IF(B2:B<>"", 1, ), A2:A&IF(B2:B<>"", 1, ), ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @player0 that too worked like a charm! I'll study it next. be well!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another similar solution.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B2:B="",,countifs(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,"<>",row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A))))
```

Comment: Thanks @ztiaa that too worked like a charm! I'll study it next. be well!